# Reading text file with bash and sending curl query

Tags: python, bash, curl

I have a text file containing data to classify:

```
facture
iphone
comment acceder
```

I have a bash script reading my text file line per line, and sending each line using curl to a classifier written in Python 3.4 and running in a Docker container. Here is the code of the script:

```
old_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $(cat file.txt) do
    echo $line
    curl -d q=$line localhost:8099/v2
    echo $'\n'
    sleep 1
done
IFS=$old_IFS
```

localhost:8099/v2 is the adress of the Docker container.
For each query, the classifier prints the probabilities of belonging to the defined classes (3 classes in our case: assistance, actu and boutique).

Let's have a look at the output of the command

```
curl -d q=facture localhost:8099/v2

{"classes": ["assistance"], "levels": {"assistance": 0.915, "boutique": 0.085, "actu": 0.0}}
```

However, when I'm running the script, I have this output:

```
facture
{"classes": ["boutique", "actu", "assistance"], "levels": {"boutique": 0.333, "actu": 0.333, "assistance": 0.333}}

iphone
{"classes": ["boutique", "actu", "assistance"], "levels": {"boutique": 0.333, "actu": 0.333, "assistance": 0.333}}

comment acceder
{"classes": ["assistance"], "levels": {"assistance": 0.886, "boutique": 0.113, "actu": 0.0}}
```

The probabilities are not correct, which leads me to think that the query is not well read by the script. This assumption is contradicted by the fact that the line is correctly printed by the script. I first thought of an encoding problem, but all my files are using utf8, and so does the terminal.

So my question is, is my script doing something wrong when reading the content of the file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess maybe is your file.txt is not unix format, try execute

```
dos2unix file.txt
```

first

Comment: You are right ! It is working now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try : `q="facture"` ?

I believe that your console needs to assume a string as a key. As it doesn't recognize the pattern, it searches for all by default ?

Comment: curl -d q="facture" prints the same as curl -d q=facture
And for the script, it prints the same results with or without the " "